# Disable Mac notifications when running Parallels in full screen?

Tags: macos, notifications, parallels-desktop

I am on a Mac running Parallels 12. When I run my Windows 10 VM in full screen mode, I don't want to see email or Slack notifications from Mac OS, just Windows 10.

How do I disable Mac OS notifications from coming through when I am running my Windows 10 VM in full screen? Otherwise, I end up seeing double notifications, one for Mac, and one for Windows.

Comment: Have you tried turning on DND on your mac? You can find it in Notification Center by scrolling upwards, this may be a manual fix and resets itself at ~8am the next day.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on Do Not Disturb mode from the notification centre quickly before entering fullscreen on parallels.

Open **Notification Center** -> Pull Down to reveal **Do Not Disturb toggle**.

[image]

Alternatively, You can go to "System Preferences" -> Notifications to set custom Do Not Disturb settings.
[image]

Comment: To quickly turn on Do Not Disturb you can option click the Notification Center icon.